# php, Dompdf, сгенерировать и скачать файл не сохраняю его в папке

Tags: php, dompdf

я использую библиотеку Dompdf

Суть такова, что я хочу генерировать файл и скачивать его но не сохранять его на диске

Код которым я пытаюсь это сделать

```
        $route = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . "/pdf-templates/invoice-pdf.php";

        ob_start();
        include $route;
        $content = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        // Load dompdf and create object
        $options = new Options();
        $options->setIsHtml5ParserEnabled(true);
        $options->setIsRemoteEnabled(true);
        $dompdf = new Dompdf($options);
        $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
        $dompdf->loadHtml($content);
        $dompdf->render();
        $output = $dompdf->output();
        $fileName = 'tested.pdf';

        $pathToPDF = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/portal-files/" . $fileName;
        $result = file_put_contents($pathToPDF, $output);

        $path_parts = pathinfo($pathToPDF);

        header("Content-type: application/pdf"); // add here more headers for diff.     extensions
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $path_parts["basename"] . "\"");     // use 'attachment' to force a download
```

Comment: и в чем проблема? получили вы `$output`, теперь закомментируйте все строки далее которые записывают его в файл, а после вывода заголовков сделайте `echo` этого аутпута

Comment: и каким образом оно скачает файл?
Если я закоментирую все что ниже output

Comment: не все что ниже, а все что после `$output =` до `header`.  скачает таким образом как предполагает протокол HTTP